# Colored arrangements of circles on the two sphere

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, pr.probability

Let me define   a **degree $n$ colored  arrangement of circles** on $S^2$ to be a   collection $\mathcal{C}$  of $n$ disjoint, smoothly embedded circles $C_1,\dotsc, C_n\subset S^2$ together with a continuous  map (temperature)

$$  T: S^2 \setminus (C_1\cup\cdots \cup C_n)\to \lbrace 1,-1\rbrace $$

such that for any  circle $C_k$,  the temperatures  on opposite sides of $C_k$  are different.  In  other words, if $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to S^2$, $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$,  is a  short smooth path  that intersects  exactly one circle  $C_k$, and it does so   transversally at $t=0$, then

$$\lim_{t\searrow 0} \; T\bigl(\; \gamma(t)\;\bigr)= - \lim_{t\nearrow 0}\;    T\bigl(\;\gamma(t)\;\bigr). $$

Think of the components of $T^{-1}(-1)$ as *icy regions* and of the components of $T^{-1}(1)$ as *liquid regions*.  We will refer to $T$ as a *coloring* of the *arrangement  of circles* $\mathcal{C}$.

Two   arrangements of  circles $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}'$ are called **equivalent**  if there exists an orientation preserving  diffeomorphism of $S^2$ that maps one arrangement to the other. We denote by $\mathcal{A}_n$ the set  of equivalence classes of  arrangements on $n$ disjoint circles on $S^2$.

Two   degree $n$ colored arrangements  $(\mathcal{C}, T)$ and $(\mathcal{C}', T')$ are called  **equivalent** if  there exists an orientation preserving diffeomorphism    $\Psi: S^2\to S^2$  mapping the circles in $\mathcal{C}$ to the circles in $\mathcal{C}'$ and such that $T'\circ \Psi= T$.

Two colorings of a given arrangement $\mathcal{C}$ of $n$ disjoint circles on $S^2$  are called **equivalent**   if the colored arrangements  $(\mathcal{C}, T)$ and $(\mathcal{C}, T')$  are equivalent.   We get in this fashion a map

$$ K_n : \mathcal{A}_n\to\mathbb{Z}$$

that associates to an arrangement $\mathcal{C}$ the nummber of inequivalent colorings of $\mathcal{C}$.  Here are some questions I find interesting.

$\mathbf{Q_0}$ Find the cardinality of $\mathcal{A}_n$ ans its large $n$ asymptotics.

$\mathbf{Q_1}$    Find the cardinality of $\mathcal{S}_n$ and its large $n$ asymptotics.

$\mathbf{Q_1^*}$ Investigate the map $K_n$.

$\mathbf{Q_2}$  We declare an colored arrangement $(\mathcal{C}, T)$ to be  **selfdual** if  it is equivalent  to $(\mathcal{C}, -T)$. Find the  number of selfdual colored arrangements of degree $n$ and  its  large $n$ asymptotics.

$\mathbf{Q_3}$  Equip $\mathcal{S}_n$ with the uniform probability density and denote by $X_n:\mathcal{S}_n\to \mathbb{R}$ the random variable o that associates to a colored arrangement $(\mathcal{C}, T)$ the  Euler characteristic of  the liquid region $T^{-1}(1)$.  Denote by $\mu_n$ the probability  distribution of $X_n$. Investigate the large $n$ behavior of $\mu_n$.

$\mathbf{Q_4}$ Can you think of a good notion of a random arrangement of $n$ disjoint circles on $S^2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the graph obtained by assigning to each region a vertex, and two vertices being joined by an edge iff the two regions are neighbors. It is easy to see that this is a tree, with the empty circles as terminal vertices: once you crossed a circle, the only way to return to the same region is by the same edge.

The tree isomorphism corresponds to the equivalence of arrangements of circles.

So the cardinality of $\mathcal A_n$ is the same as for the [unlabeled trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_graph#Unlabeled_trees). In the same wiki reference is mentioned he asymptotic estimate given by Otter (1948). For the cardinality of $\mathcal A_n$ is no known formula.

For the $\mathcal S_n$, there are only two ways to color a tree so that each edge connects two vertices of opposite colors. They may be not distinct (*i.e.* may be **selfdual**), since it is possible to have a tree automorphism which switches the colors. The asymptotics is similar to the uncolored case, because there are only one or two distinct colorings of the same tree.

The notion of [randomness for trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_tree) depends on the purpose.

The answers are partial, mainly because the answers to the corresponding questions for the trees are partial known, but I hope that the connection with trees may help.